# "Ну". Пунктуация

Tags: пунктуация

В каких случаях после "ну" ставится запятая?

Например: Ну() ладно.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Спешу обрадовать Вас: все просто и прозрачно, как явствует из [данной статьи](http://www.gramota.ru/spravka/punctum/58_501), ключевыми словами в которой являются следующие: "Зачастую сложно различить частицу «ну» и междометие «ну» по значению. В этих случаях следует ориентироваться на интонацию".

Comment: Х-м! "Ну и что?!", "Ну так что?", "Ну а ты где был?", "Ну-у, не всегда надо соблюдать правила пунктуации", "Ну-ну, продолжайте!", "Ну-ка, ну-ка, что за штука?", "Ну, если так, то, конечно, это правильно", "Ну зачем Вы меня поцеловали тогда?!","Ну не всегда я не интеллигентен", "Ну уж..." (почти аналог знаменитой фразы Кисы Воробьянинова), "Ну ладно, согласен", "Ну, ладно: согласен!" и т. д. и т. д.