# «Ну» и запятая

Tags: пунктуация

> — И где его похоронили? — спросил я.
> — Что? — не поняли мальчишки. 
> — Ну(,) где вы его закопали?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Да всяк корректно, [уж сколько раз твердили миру](https://rus.stackexchange.com/questions/29803/%D0%BD%D1%83-%D0%BF%D1%83%D0%BD%D0%BA%D1%82%D1%83%D0%B0%D1%86%D0%B8%D1%8F).

Answer (score 0):

Совершено верно. Запятая альтернативна.