# В чем смысл частицы "НУ"?

Tags: частица

Для чего используется частица "НУ" в следующих предложениях:
- Ну, ты понял;
- Ну, понял;
- Ну, погоди.
И нужно ли выделять ее запятой?

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: ["Ну". Пунктуация](https://rus.stackexchange.com/questions/29803/%d0%9d%d1%83-%d0%9f%d1%83%d0%bd%d0%ba%d1%82%d1%83%d0%b0%d1%86%d0%b8%d1%8f)

Comment: Всё-таки надо иметь ввиду, что есть Поиск по сайту.

Answer (score 3):

Вопрос не простой. Слово *ну* может быть частицей или междометием. Подробно о его смысле и роли см. в [Большом толковом словаре](http://gramota.ru/slovari/dic/?word=%D0%BD%D1%83&all=x&lop=x&bts=x&ro=x&zar=x&ag=x&ab=x&sin=x&lv=x&az=x&pe=x)

Тема обсуждалась неоднократно на этом сайте (используйте окно поиска и найдите сами).

Рекомендую [Ответ Граммы.ру](https://rus.stackexchange.com/questions/419933/%D0%9F%D1%80%D0%BE%D1%82%D0%B8%D0%B2%D0%BE%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B6%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%B5-%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B8%D0%BC%D0%B5%D1%80%D1%8B-%D1%81-%D0%BD%D1%83), в который они в конечном итоге советуют при постановке запятой ориентироваться на интонацию.

Конкретные примеры из Вашего вопроса.

**Ну ты понял!**

> Употр. для придания высказыванию большей силы, выразительности, подчёркивает значение того или другого слова. Ну конечно, это неправда. Ну какой холод! Ну что за жизнь: ни денег, ни чести
>
> Головоногие ― это голова и ноги, а человек ― это голова и пол… ну ты понял. [Сергей Осипов. Страсти по Фоме. Книга третья. Книга Перемен (1998)]

**Ну, ты понял.**

> Подчёркивает заключительный характер высказывания. Ну, и гости разъехались. Ну, этим дело и кончилось. Ну, я пойду. Ну, пора чай пить.
>
> ― Нефтепре. пере. Ну, ты понял. ― Я понял, но я понятия не имею. [Олег Дивов. Молодые и сильные выживут (1998)]

**Ну, ты понял?**
Побуждение к ответу

> выражение нетерпеливого побуждения, призыва к действию. Ну, давай плясать! Ну, рассказывай. Идём быстрее, ну! Ну, подойди
>
> Ну, ты понял, о чем я, да?.. [Евгений Лукин. В стране заходящего солнца (1999)]

**Ну понял!**

> Употр. для придания высказыванию большей силы, выразительности
>
> ― Ну понял, понял, Кондромо, ― улыбающимся голосом ответил Окоемов. [Михаил Тарковский. Кондромо // «Октябрь», 2003]

**Ну, понял.**

> Употр. для выражения настороженности
>
> «Таблица умножения точка таблица уважения точка таблица спряжения точка задавайте вопросы точка». ― Понял?! ― спросил восхищенный Непоседа. ― Ну, понял… Вот возьму задам ему сейчас пример на умножение, он и провалится. «Задавайте вопросы точка!» ― прошипел остров. [Ефим Чеповецкий. Непоседа, Мякиш и Нетак (1989)]

**Ну, погоди!**

> выражение нетерпеливого побуждения, призыва к действию. Ну, давай плясать! Ну, рассказывай. Идём быстрее, ну! Ну, подойди.

«Ну, погоди́!» — советский и российский мультсериал. ([Википедия](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9D%D1%83,_%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%B3%D0%BE%D0%B4%D0%B8!))

Comment: Спасибо за развернутый ответ. В который раз удивляюсь насколько выразителен, но в то же время сложен русский язык. Слово "НУ" вроде всего то состоит из двух букв, но в скольких "фантиках" его можно завернуть. Выделил интонацией - один смысл, не выделил - другой смысл. Как дети все это понимают. Интуитивно наверное.