# Нужно ли ставить запятую после "Ну" в приведенном предложении?

Tags: пунктуация, запятые

Фраза: "Ну прошу прощения!"
Также встречается фраза без восклицания. Нужно ли ставить запятую после ну с восклицанием? А без восклицания?

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: ["Ну". Пунктуация](https://rus.stackexchange.com/questions/29803/%d0%9d%d1%83-%d0%9f%d1%83%d0%bd%d0%ba%d1%82%d1%83%d0%b0%d1%86%d0%b8%d1%8f)

Answer (score 1):

Как используется словечко [**НУ**](http://gramota.ru/slovari/dic/?word=%D0%BD%D1%83&all=x) и какова при этом пунктуация можно посмотреть в толковом словаре.

О частице "ну" и о междометии "ну" на сайте говорилось уже много раз. Наберите в "поиске" *ну частица* — появится много ответов.
Вот, как мне кажется, очень интересный (об ошибке в словаре):
[Противоположные примеры с “ну”](https://rus.stackexchange.com/questions/419933/%D0%9F%D1%80%D0%BE%D1%82%D0%B8%D0%B2%D0%BE%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B6%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%B5-%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B8%D0%BC%D0%B5%D1%80%D1%8B-%D1%81-%D0%BD%D1%83/420036#420036).

Без контекста (а Вы его не приводите) сложно различить частицу и междометие, потому что необходимо ориентироваться на интонацию: междометие выделяется паузой, а частица — нет.

Представим себе диалог (кто-то настойчиво требует принести извинения).
*— Тебе нужно извиниться. Говори, я жду. **Ну,** прошу прощения!* [междометие]
*— Ладно-ладно, хорошо, уговорил. **Ну** прошу прощения!* [усилит. частица]

В качестве примера можно привести отрывок из стихотворения Евгения Евтушенко, где первое "ну" — это частица (без запятой), а второе — междометие.

> "Видишь, небо какое синее?
>   Слышишь, птицы какие в лесу?
>   **Ну** так что же ты? **Ну?** Неси меня!"
>   А куда я тебя понесу?..

Comment: Не вижу в этом примере "ну" междометием!

Comment: Простите, Артём, — в каком примере?

Comment: Где кто-то настойчиво требует принести извинения. Первый.

Comment: Ну почему же не междометие? Выражает настойчивое побуждение к тому, чтобы сказать _прошу прощения_. Именно эту фразу и повторяет второй участник. Конечно, если автору вопроса достаточно той абстрактной информации, на которую ссылается _shampar_ при закрытии вопроса, можно бесполезный ответ и удалить. _Спешу обрадовать Вас: все просто и прозрачно, как явствует из данной статьи, ключевыми словами в которой являются следующие: "Зачастую сложно различить частицу «ну» и междометие «ну» по значению. В этих случаях следует ориентироваться на интонацию_  (статьи нет) — где здесь решение вопроса?

Comment: @АртёмЛуговой Ваш вопрос и ответы к нему я ведь не зря привела — в них много полезной информации, есть рассуждения, примеры.

Comment: Я просто не могу представить себе такой интонации.